# <?php if(! empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'))) { ?>

Tags: php, error-handling, codeigniter-3

When any PHP page loads for example: Logout . The page i'm sent to appears blank with a error message pointing me to a line of code:

```
<?php if(! empty($this->session->userdata('user_id')))  {  ?>
```

This peace of code is supposedly wrong and is the reason pages load blank.
Please help... whats wrong?

Comment: This question is not duplicated *John Conde*

Comment: ISSUE FIXED!  line must be like this: <?php if( ! $this->session->userdata('user_id')) ?>